# How to apply ng-repeat on carousel with multiple items using angular js?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

```
<div class="carousel slide" id="myCarousel">
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item active">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-3 home__li-align" ng-
                     repeat="electronic in allItem.slice(0,4) | filter :enter code here 'electronics'">
                        <a ui-sref="" ng-click="`enter code here`view(mobile)">
                            <img ng-src="../asset/img/{{electronic.image[0]}}"  alt="Not Found" style="height: 200px;width:50%;" />
                            <div class="home__label-align">{{electronic.product_name}}</div>
                            <div class="home__label-align"> ₹: {{electronic.cost}}</div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-3 home__li-align" ng-repeat="electronic in allItem.slice(4,8) | filter : 'electronics'">
                        <a ui-sref="" ng-click="view(mobile)">
                            <img ng-src="../asset/img/{{electronic.image[0]}}"  alt="Not Found" style="height: 200px;width:50%;" />
                            <div class="home__label-align">{{electronic.product_name}}</div>
                            <div class="home__label-align"> ₹: {{electronic.cost}}</div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev"  style="margin-bottom: 70px; margin-left: -70px;  color: black;"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" ></i></a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next"  style="margin-bottom: 70px; margin-right: -70px;  color: black;"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></a>
    </div>
```

Only item active class is working and i want 4 div in one slide of carousel then on clicking carousel control. It should bring next carousel having 4 div.So any Solution of that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can understand your problem and i created solution fiddle please follow below link.

```
<script>
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

//myApp.directive('myDirective', function() {});
//myApp.factory('myService', function() {});
myApp.controller("MyCtrl",MyCtrl);
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.list = [];
     for(var i = 0; i< 16;i++){
     $scope.list.push(i);
     }
}
</script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">


<div  id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-3" style="height:100px; background:red; color:green; font-size:18px;" ng-repeat="l in list.slice(0,4)">
         Hello  {{l}}
        </div>
    </div>

    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-3" style="height:100px; background:red; color:green; font-size:18px;" ng-repeat="l in list.slice(4,8)">
         Hello  {{l}}
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/450x350" alt="Slide 3">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        Caption Slide 3
      </div>
    </div>        
  </div>

  <!-- Controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/r2wLz6xr/507/

Comment: Thank u Sir, but its not working. please check answer again because 2 ng-repeat are used by you.

Comment: i want something like flipkart applied when we select mobile then slider having 4-5 items in first show

Comment: @DJ i write a fiddle same like your problem may it solves your problem.